# tcolorbox documentation: preventing space between head and body

Tags: spacing, tcolorbox

I'm using `tcolorbox` to document some commands, and I would like to have a slight background color on the body text of the command explanations. I have the below MWE to show this by wrapping the body in its own tcolorbox with a `colback` value.

However, I would like to remove the white space between the head and the body, such that they are directly connected. I have tried adjusting the boxes via `nobeforeafter` and `before/after skip`s without luck.

I suspect that the body (and thus the tcolorbox that I create with the `before/after doc body` keys in the preamble) is wrapped in something, but I don't know how to access and change it.

[image: example]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{documentation}

\tcbset{
    doc head={
        interior style={fill,color=blue!10},
        boxsep=2pt,
        after skip=0pt,
        nobeforeafter,
        %show bounding box,
    },
    before doc body={
        \begin{tcolorbox}[
            colback=blue!5,
            colframe=blue!5,
            arc=0pt,
            outer arc=0pt,
            before skip=0pt,
            nobeforeafter,
        ]
    },
    after doc body={\end{tcolorbox}},
}


\begin{document}

\begin{docCommand}
    {myCommand}
    {\marg{argument}}
    Some description of the command. Blah blah blah.
\end{docCommand}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doc head `tcolorbox` is placed within a `tcbraster`, which has a default after skip of 4.1pt. This needs to be set to 0pt using `doc raster={raster after skip=0pt}` and then the gap is removed:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{documentation}

\tcbset{
    doc head={
        interior style={fill,color=blue!10},
        boxsep=2pt,
    },
    doc raster={raster after skip=0pt},
    before doc body={
        \begin{tcolorbox}[
            colback=blue!5,
            colframe=blue!5,
            arc=0pt,
            outer arc=0pt,
            before skip=0pt,
        ]
    },
    after doc body={\end{tcolorbox}},
}


\begin{document}

\begin{docCommand}
    {myCommand}
    {\marg{argument}}
    Some description of the command. Blah blah blah.
\end{docCommand}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Excellent, many thanks!

Comment: Is it also possible to prevent page breaks between head & body? I tried adding `before={\needspace{10\baselineskip}}` to `doc raster` but that had no effect (with `\usepackage{needspace}` in preamble)

Comment: @meide, it might be best to ask a new question with example code that reproduces your problem, then more people will see your question.

Comment: Alright, thanks :)

Comment: For future reference, I did it by patching an internal tcolorbox environment in my preamble: `\AtBeginEnvironment{tcb@manual@entry}{\needspace{10\baselineskip}}`